# how to upload a image with html and java without scriplet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

The think is i need to upload a image to my project, using just html and java (JSP, Servlet & JSTL) i can't use Scriplet (<% %>) , soo its a bit difficult for me.. im actually studying.

I know i need to use "file" & "Stream"

```
<form method="POST" action="servletTest">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
                <input type ="file" value="What File?"></input>
                <input type ="submit" enctype='multipart/form-data' value="Upload"</input>
</form>
```

Now here is mi question, what do i need to do in my Servlet?
How can i take the url of the "file" and save it ? can i upload the file to my DataBase ? how ?

i know its a lot of work but im a little (A LOT) lost :c
PD:Sorry for my english im from chile and we speak spanish :(

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nothing is difficult, believe me ;-). You can find excellent answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/1401019

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy Thanks !!! That its what i need !! very helpfully ;) Thanks a lot :D